# torrc doesn't contain the "location-hidden services" section

Tags: linux-mint, tor

I'm trying to create a `.onion` website, but my `torrc` file doesn't contain the

```
############### This section is just for location-hidden services ###
```

part, instead, it contains only this:

```
# This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
.# The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1, and Tor will ignore it
ClientOnionAuthDir /home/fox/tor/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/onion-auth
DataDirectory /home/fox/tor/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor
GeoIPFile /home/fox/tor/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/geoip
GeoIPv6File /home/fox/tor/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/geoip6
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You tagged Linux Mint, which is not exactly the best choice for a Tor relay, I'd recommend Debian 11, on which I'm running a server with a relay.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, jk, problem solved!
Apparently, for some reason, the command to install tor on mint didn’t want to work, (no idea the reason behind it, maybe I’ve done some syntax errors). I’ve tried this again on a Pi, and used the command to install tor, and there it worked: the torrc file contained the

```
This section is just for location-hidden services…
```

Comment: What exact commands or what solved the issue?